# Getting sum from two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sum

I have two tables.

```
Voucher 
V_Id Cost
1     400
2     500

Expense 
E_Id  V_Id  Cost
1      1     100
2      1     100
3      1     100
```

I need to join them so that I get

```
V_Id  V_Cost  E_Cost
1      400     300
2      500      0
```

I have tried INNER JOIN but I get the same value fro both of them. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I took the Expense table's SUM(Cost) as E_Cost, then Left join with Voucher to get the expected result:

```
SELECT V.V_Id, V.Cost AS V_Cost, ISNULL(E.E_Cost, 0) AS E_Cost
FROM Voucher V
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT V_Id, SUM(Cost) AS E_Cost
             FROM Expense 
             GROUP BY V_Id ) AS E ON E.V_Id = V.V_Id
```

Working example with given data:

```
DECLARE @Voucher TABLE (V_Id INT, Cost INT)
INSERT INTO @Voucher (V_Id, Cost)
VALUES (1, 400), (2, 500)

DECLARE @Expense TABLE (E_Id INT, V_Id INT, Cost INT)
INSERT INTO @Expense (E_Id, V_Id, Cost)
VALUES (1, 1, 100), (2, 1, 100), (3, 1, 100)

SELECT V.V_Id, V.Cost AS V_Cost, ISNULL(E.E_Cost, 0) AS E_Cost
FROM @Voucher V
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT V_Id, SUM(Cost) AS E_Cost
             FROM @Expense 
             GROUP BY V_Id ) AS E ON E.V_Id = V.V_Id
```